# How to configure a Git Work-flow like this? "Only one user can push to the central server(bare repo)"

Tags: git

I will work with one designer that does not know anything of Git. I need to setup an Work-flow where I need to give permission to the code that the designer uploads to the central server.

I'm a newbie in Git. How can I setup a Work-flow like this(Designer must to submit the code for approval)?

It is also possible to receive notifications of pending code for approval?

Best Regards,

Comment: Re: [patch queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952651/git-equivalent-to-hg-mq) Re: [code review](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a second repository, where the designer can commit his changes at will. You can then pull the changes, merge it into your workspace and review it. When everything is fine, push it to your "main" repository.

Or maybe you can create a commit hook, so the designer can only commit to a single branch (`designers-name/develop` or such). Now its the same as above: Fetch the changes, review, merge into the branch you want to keep control over and push back. Maybe you don't need a hook here, because everybody should be able to follow a rule like "never push into the branches X and Y yourself" ;)