# Track and apply changes from a project's tag

Tags: git, github

There is a git project on github I want to reorganize for my work. Each time the project is tagged on github, I want to apply my changes to it so that am able to keep my changes current to the original project. I need help with a workflow for this. I am familiar with git basics and nothing advanced. Clear steps would help make this understandable.

Comment: Simply merge the project's changes into your own repository. If you feel funky and prefer a more linear history, use rebase instead of merge.

Comment: Rebase seems better than merge. What I am hoping for is a workflow of  some steps that I can perform from tracking to rebasing each time. I only want to update from a tag from the original project when I know it has been tagged because changes in the original project's master may still be unreleased.

Comment: Or you looking for an automated way to do that or are you asking how to rebase on top of a tag/merge a tag?

Comment: You might have to clarify what you mean by "reorganize". If you mean moving files/directories or file contents around to create a different layout of the project code, that's not going to be easy to automate. But if you mean something more like rebasing/merging your own private branches to take advantage of upstream changes, that's fairly easy...

Comment: @twalberg I want to maintain the code in a different structure than the original. This includes make changes to where folders and files are located.  I don't expect that the original project will change that much for structure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a remote **origin**, and you want to update your local master branch with the newer commits from the version **v5.0**

1. `git fetch`
2. `git checkout -b master`
3. `git pull --rebase origin v5.0`

This way you'll have your local branch updated with all the commits from **v5.0** and your commits.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I think I need to have a remote for the original, a local version that I will need to keep up to date with the last tag, then rebase my master with the tagged version. At least this is what I am getting from reading so far. I think this helps but I may be missing something or this may not be complete.

Comment: Can you add more information in the question as why this is not working for you? Did you clone the repository you're trying to get updates from?

Comment: I found this which is close to what I am looking to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660883/how-to-achieve-a-private-branch-in-git-that-floats-when-merging-with-upstream but still trying to get this worked out.

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference from that question? If so, please update the question to reflect your problem.